# Restrict Google Maps API key for us in Private Google Access environment

Tags: google-maps, networking, google-cloud-platform

I have an application running in a VM on GCP with no external IP address.  The application is within a VPC which has "Google Private Access" enabled allowing the application to make use of googles maps API without having public internet access.

I have created an API Key which has access to the geocoding api and works when there are no IP restrictions.  However when I try and restrict the key to the CIDR for my VMs (172.16.0.0/24) I get an error returned from google something like the following:

```
# curl "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=${GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}"
{
   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address fda3:e722:ac3:10:4a:dc74:ac10:5, with empty referer",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

I'm not sure where that IP is coming from, I assume it is part of the infrastructure Google is using to keep the request within GCP and not go out over the internet.  But I'm not clear as to what values would be safe to put in to restrict the usage of the key.

Comment: It is not exactly clear to me how you set up your private network since this seems to be primarily the difference between your api calls. Could you please elaborate more on that and share any document or webpage you may be following? I have found in the next link that you can set up 199.36.153.8/30 as a range but again I am not sure if the document describes the setup you have. https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/set-up-private-connectivity

Comment: The best description of my configuration is: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-access-options#pga  The application request would be coming from VM A1 in the diagram.

Comment: You can simply copy and paste that value(fda3:e722:ac3:10:4a:dc74:ac10:5) in the section "Accept requests from these server IP addresses" and the message should stop appearing when you call the Geocoding API.

Comment: Yes I tried that Antonio but it keeps changing, and I have no idea where it is getting it from

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are making a Geocoding API web request on cloud environment. According to the [API Key best practices](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#api_key_table), API keys for web services does support only IP address restriction. However, IP restrictions might be impractical, such as in mobile applications and cloud environments that rely on `dynamic` IP addresses. When using Maps Web Service APIs in these scenarios, you can secure your apps using one or more of the following techniques:

- proxy server
- obfuscation
- pinning

Although I am not an expert when it comes to VMs, it is also possible that the VM actually has a static IP, which is what you could be seeing in the response (fda3:e722:ac3:10:4a:dc74:ac10:5). One way to confirm this is to restrict your API Key with that IP address and see if it works even after restarting your VM.

Also, I noticed that you mentioned you can use Maps API services without having public internet access. So it's possible that there is some downloading going on. When it comes to this, please take note of the [Terms of Service](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/#3.-license) under 3.2.3 (a. No Scraping).